# setState is not working inside event function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I have declared on constructor,

```
this.onProjectSelect.bind(this);
```

Ths is outside render and outside of constructor,

```
onProjectSelect(event) {
    this.setState({project: event.target.value});
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

JSX View

```
<Select2
data={BasicStore.projectsSelect2Format}
onChange={this.onProjectSelect}
options={{
    placeholder: 'Search Project',
}}
/>
```

I don't understand my mistakes here. Please help me to to get out of here. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you *just* calling `this.onProjectSelect.bind(this);` or are you assigning it back go `this.onProjectSelect`? The [`bind` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns a *new* function, so I would expect to see:

```
this.onProjectSelect = this.onProjectSelect.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could be missing the state initializing on the constructor, or maybe you are just making a mistake in the binding. I would do something like this:

```
export default class Test extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      project: ''
    }
  }

  onProjectSelect = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      project: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Select2
        data={BasicStore.projectsSelect2Format}
        onChange={this.onProjectSelect}
        options={{
          placeholder: 'Search Project',
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: using an arrow function is a more succinct solution than the accepted answer, IMO